# What kind of lighting does the ISS use?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, environment

Is any feng shui used in lighting? Is the best light bulbs used with filters?

Comment: Strongly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/why-are-these-astronauts-green

Comment: Don't mention feng shui, it is so... nasty on the space SE. Nearly surely no feng shui was used to plan the lighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feng Shui is not used. The ISS is a science lab and Feng Shui is not scientific.

Currently, [fluorescent lighting](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/2279.html) is used. A study is underway to replace this with LED lighting.

> The Testing Solid State Lighting Countermeasures to Improve Circadian Adaptation, Sleep, and Performance During High Fidelity Analog and Flight Studies for the International Space Station (Lighting Effects) investigation studies the impact of the change from fluorescent light bulbs to solid-state light-emitting diodes (LEDs) with adjustable intensity and color and aims to determine if the new lights can improve crew circadian rhythms, sleep, and cognitive performance.

Comment: I've just asked [Since there is no proper "ceiling" in the ISS where do they put the lights?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26975/12102)