# Since there is no proper "ceiling" in the ISS where do they put the lights?

Tags: iss

After reading [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26961/12102) I started to think more about ISS lighting.

In photos and videos from the ISS, the lighting seems to somewhat isotropic; I don't see many strong shadows "behind" or "under" the astronauts or other large objects, and people are fairly well lit from what looks like many sides. Though not perfect, the lighting is definitely more than a bare 60W bulb dangling from a cord in the middle of the <s>room</s> module.

In fact, I also don't recall ever seeing any of the light sources.

Where are the lights "hidden" and how is this ubiquitous lighting of the whole volume accomplished?

Comment: The interior arrangement of the ISS is such that one side is clearly identifiable as the cieling and one side is identifyable as the floor. That makes it easier for the kosmonauts to find stuff.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi I didn't know that, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There are fluorescent tubes](https://urbanfragment.wordpress.com/tag/nasa/) on the corner between the side walls and the ceiling.

[image: Interior view of the Destiny laboratory]

Interior view of the Destiny laboratory.

Comment: That's a beautiful photo! It's not as glamorous as some. I guess with so many light-colored surfaces and rows of lights on both sides, the light reflects a few times and becomes somewhat more isotropic.