# What's the small white gadget with two black buttons in this video of the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, video, hatch

Does anyone know what's the small white square gadget with two black buttons on the right hand side of the hatch frame in this video on the second 2185 (36:25 minutes)?

[image]

I've been looking everywhere but I can't get a clearer image or information about it, and it seems to be next to almost every hatch of the ISS.

Comment: That's the call button for the space elevator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll try and find a better picture, but it's the light switch.

Labeled GENERAL LIGHTING, buttons ON and OFF

[image]

Cropped from [https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s130e007774/s130e007774~orig.jpg](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s130e007774/s130e007774%7Eorig.jpg)

The best picture I could find is cropped from https://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/images/recherche/hi-res/7ca21bfc-2a90-4dd9-9e22-a3b13d323a18.jpg

[image]

I could find no documentation about it on NASA websites :( I did find this info in the *International Space Station
Expedition Crew
Training Notebook* (personal copy)

[image]

Comment: Is there a new, separate control for "General Lighting Color" as well? [Is the new RGB solid state LED lighting on the ISS ever used to produce colors other than white?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37274/12102) remains unanswered.

Comment: @uhoh ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I love that NASA feels their best and brightest might need to have it explained to them how a light switch works. 

Comment: Maybe that button needs to be pressed harder than a home light switch, and the italicised "Firmly" was added after the Best and Brightest had to be told "try again but harder this time"

Comment: Is that a common light switch layout in the US? Or is it something NASA had made for the ISS specifically?

Comment: @Sixtyfive push-button light switches are kind of old school in the US. https://www.thisoldhouse.com/electrical/21302423/push-button-antique-light-switch Most domestic light switches here are toggles. No reference, but I am 100% sure these were specially made for the ISS.

Comment: I've just asked  [Are toggle- or rocker-type switches avoided in crewed areas of space stations to avoid getting accidentally bumped?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53768/12102) and also [How does the ISS crew adjust the color of the new LED cabin lighting? Is there a knob somewhere? Can it be programmed to change by itself?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53769/12102)