# Are toggle- or rocker-type switches avoided in crewed areas of space stations to avoid getting accidentally bumped?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, space-station, safety, electronics

[@OrganicMarble's answer to *What's the small white gadget with two black buttons in this video of the International Space Station?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52283/12102) includes the On/Off switch for cabin lighting aboard the ISS.

There are *two buttons*, one for ON and one for OFF.

Comments there remark at it being a bit usual for a wall switch for a room light, and I'd guess that recessed buttons that have to be pressed *firmly* (as the image notes) are resistant to inadvertent actuation.

**Question:** Are toggle- or rocker-type switches avoided in cabin areas of space stations or **in non flight-deck areas of** other large spacecraft (e.g. shuttles) to avoid getting accidentally bumped and actuated?

**note:** Historically there have been toggle switches in flight decks or capsules, I'm not asking about those areas.

> [image: https://i.imgur.com/xrybb4Y.png]

Comment: *Apollo Experience Report: Crew Station Displays and Controls* (D-7919, p. 10) mentions switches with a locking mechanism, recessing them in a trough, and guard wickets.  But you seem to not want such an answer.

Comment: @DrSheldon yes that would be a different question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

> Are toggle- or rocker-type switches avoided in cabin areas of space stations or in non flight-deck areas of other large spacecraft (e.g. shuttles) to avoid getting accidentally bumped and actuated?

For shuttles, no.

The Orbiter's middeck (the level of the crew cabin below the flight deck) had many panels in it covered liberally with the same type of toggle switches and circuit breakers found on the flight deck.  It even had manual-lever-operated valves for its cabin air system.

Here are a few examples

[image]

[image]

The panels were scattered around the middeck, but most were located on its ceiling or towards the aft of the side walls.

[image]

Sources

- [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf)
- [Location Coding Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383448main_jsc_26419.pdf)

Comment: Lots of switch guards though, IIRC...