# Exterior "running lights" on ISS?

Tags: iss, design-alternative

In Scott Kelley's memoir "Endurance," he describes how challenging it is to navigate the exterior of ISS when in Earth's shadow, and he mentions that his Russian colleagues would just stay put and rest during that time.

Why doesn't the ISS have external running lights? I understand that there is generally not a shortage of electrical power, and LEDs are lightweight and long-lasting (at least on Earth). It seems to me that given their benefits to safety during spacewalks, there must be a reason for their absence.

Comment: It's worth remembering that while LEDs for indication purposes have been around for a long time, LEDs for lighting purposes are much newer. It wasn't until the mid 1990s that the high efficiency blue LEDs needed for LED lighting was developed and some time after that before they became mainstream.

Comment: @PeterGreen Indeed, they only recently got *indoor* LED lighting: [Why are these astronauts green?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22876/12102) and [Is the new RGB solid state LED lighting on the ISS ever used to produce colors other than white?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37274/12102) and especially [How does the ISS crew adjust the color of the new LED cabin lighting? Is there a knob somewhere? Can it be programmed to change by itself?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53769/12102)

Comment: I honestly don't think there's a reason.  It hasn't been necessary yet, so no one has championed doing the power cable runs and hardware shipment and spacewalk planning it'd take to get the lighting out there.